# Unable to get data using retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

Hello I am trying to use retrofit But I am getting this error:-

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Bind(R.id.activity_main_tv_display)
TextView textData;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
@OnClick(R.id.activity_main_btn_show)
void press() {
    RemoteApi.Factory.getInstance().getModel().enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
            textData.setText(response.toString());
            Log.e("--success--", String.valueOf(response));
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("--fail--", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

This is my model

```
public class Model {

@SerializedName("Title")
@Expose
private String Title;
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String Message;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;
// getters and setters declare
}
```

Here is my interface

```
public interface RemoteApi {

String BASE_URL = "xyz/";
@GET("api/Cards")
Call<Model> getModel();
class Factory {
    public static RemoteApi remoteApi;
    public static RemoteApi getInstance() {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .build();
            remoteApi = retrofit.create(RemoteApi.class);
            return remoteApi;
        }
    }
}
```

And My API looks like this

```
[{
  "Title": "xyz",
  "Message": "hello",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "Title": "abc",
  "Message": "hello",
  "id": 2
}]
```

Comment: Your API is returning a JSON Array. Retrofit is expecting `Callback<Model>`. Try `Callback<List<Model>>`

Comment: can you explain more @cricket_007 please

Comment: Data within `{}` is a JSON object. And data within `[]` is a JSON array. Look at the first character of your API. It is a `[`. Thus, your error is reporting that it "`was BEGIN_ARRAY`", and not "`BEGIN_OBJECT`".

Comment: But when I am editing my interface from Call<Model> getModel() to  Callback<List<Model>> getModel(). It is creating error in my MainActivity ie cannot resolve method enqueue @cricket_007

Comment: That's because you have to change `Model` to `List<Model>` in all places you have `Callback` and `Call`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get a List of objects from your API (by looking at the first character), but your error states it expected an Object (also, by looking at the first character). You are using `Call<Model>` in your interface, which states you only want one `Model` object returned, not a list of them.

Try setting your interface like so

```
public interface RemoteApi {

    String BASE_URL = "xyz/";
    @GET("api/Cards")
    Call<List<Model>> getModel();
```

And the other code like this

```
RemoteApi.Factory.getInstance().getModel().enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> response) {
            String responseString = String.valueOf(response);
            textData.setText(responseString);
            Log.e("--success--", responseString);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Model>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("--fail--", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: But it is  display  retrofit2.Response@41ce5630 not the result @cricket_007

Comment: Yes, that's because you are doing `String.valueOf(response)`. Try `response.body()` instead of `response`

Comment: Log.e is displaying [examples.sewoyebah.com.retrofit.model.Model@41cfd158, examples.sewoyebah.com.retrofit.model.Model@41c5ee70]

Comment: Yup, that is a list of your model objects. Please refer to [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)